# read_excel: Import empty cells as missing values (na)

Tags: r, excel, na

I'm using read_excel to import data into R. Sometimes the specific cell in the excel file is empty. I want R to record this as na and not to ignore that cell. Currently, R doesn't import anything.

I've read through the R Documentation on read_excel and found that, by default, read_excel treats blank cells as missing data. But instead of not importing anything, I'd like to have the actual information that these data are missing. I couldn't find information on how to do that.

In the excel file A1 in sheet 1 does not contain any data.

```
x <- read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = 1, range="A1", col_names = FALSE)
```

Expected result: x 1 obs. of 1 variable, the value should be NA

Actual result: x 0 obs. of 0 variables

Comment: Treating blank cells as missing data means that blank cells are read as `NA`. Your example probably doesn't return anything because you don't really have any data. If you just fill A1 with a column name and try `read_excel("file.xlsx", range = "A2")` you should get your column name and an NA.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; that implies that if I try to import single empty cells, R does not fill the variable with NA, correct?

Comment: There's an open issue about that: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/550

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, I wasn't aware of that. Great that you pointed me to that.

Comment: @da_the It's supposed to be `range = "A1:A2"` in my previous comment to get the column name and the `NA`. I think the issue isn't really with having no data but having no column names.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that could work in the above example is to use:

```
x <- as.numeric(read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = 1, range="A1", col_names = FALSE))
```

It is not so elegant- R translates the tibble of 0x0 into NA. (Note: it will also change any strings into NA).

I don't think it works for importing more than one cell.

If anybody finds a more elegant and more generally applicable solution, that would be helpful.